# yii rendering images stored in images folder in final view

Tags: php, yii

In my web application I need to  display the images uploaded when creating in the view. The uploaded images are stored in  /images/xxx  folder . I want in such a way that as soon as the user uploads the image, it should appear in the final view. I know we  should create an array reference pointing to the images/xxx folder in config/main.php . But I  dont know how to refer to the individual images in the folder and print them in the final view..
My code for params in config/main.php

```
 'params'=>array(

        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
        'vegImageLoc'=>'images/xxx',
    ),
);
```

I dont know how to refer to the individual array elements in the final view and print them in the final view. Any body help me how to proceed.

Comment: do you want to show all images from the folder?

Comment: yes..Like I want to display the images in a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you think you need to change anything in config, maybe I'm missing something, but if you want to show all images in a folder like **`images/xxx`** , I recommend to do this :

```
 foreach (glob("images/xxx/*") as $img) {

     echo "<img src ='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/".$img."' />";
 }
```

Or if you want to get the images from database, get it and again make a `foreach` like above.

Comment: or else can i directly   render the views stored in the database?

Comment: render the views from database ? what do you mean?

Comment: are the images stored in database?

Comment: I meant  viewing them by creating a link(yii::app()->request->baseUrl) in the view

Comment: Ya In my application the user uploads the image and that image gets stored in the /images folder

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = $model->getImages(); // function to get image list stored in db. return as array
```

Pass `$image` to view file.

In your view file. you can do as below:

```
foreach ($image as $img) {

     echo "<img src ='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/".Yii::app()->params["vegImageLoc"]."/".$img."' />";
 }
```